# Cannot execute an ICommand from code behind

Tags: wix, installation, icommand

I have a WIX installer custom BA. In it I have 2 buttons. In the click event handlers I set some variables so I can only determine which features of the product I need to install. When I execute the InstallCommand it doesn't start the install, instead the log says canceling...

My code is...

```
this.InstallCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => this.model.PlanAction(LaunchAction.Install), () => this.State == InstallState.NotPresent);

public InstallView(InstallViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;

        model = viewModel.model;

        this.Closed += (sender, e) => viewModel.CancelCommand.Execute(this);

    }

    private void btnInstallClientOnly_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.SetInstallClient("InstallClient", 1);
        model.SetInstallServer("InstallServer", 0);

        if (viewModel.InstallCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            model.LogMessage("Executing Install Command");
            viewModel.InstallCommand.Execute(null);
        }

        this.Close();
    }
```

The log shows...

```
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:01]i001: Burn v3.8.1128.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: J:\Software\Gurusetup.exe, cmdline: '-l installer.txt -burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{A1F2A561-63B7-4764-9287-A49EC349D6B5} {80E463D6-6AA5-43A2-9B39-7AA6705242A8} 4932'
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'J:\Software\installer.txt'
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'J:\Software\Gurusetup.exe'
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Guru'
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:01]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:01]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:02]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:02]i102: Detected related bundle: {0d2675f0-1921-40ff-9a7b-83c2ad0886d2}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.4.0, operation: None
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:02]i101: Detected package: SQLBundle, state: Absent, cached: None
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:02]i101: Detected package: Client, state: Present, cached: None
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:02]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0F60:1040][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallClient' to value 1
[0F60:1040][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallServer' to value 0
[0F60:1040][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i000: Executing Install Command
[0F60:1040][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i000: Canceling...
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: InstallClient = 1
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: InstallServer = 0
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = J:\Software\installer.txt
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Guru Dental
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = Guru
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = J:\Software\Gurusetup.exe
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {08b31e02-bca5-4816-88fb-56ba0d62a692}
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 6.0.4.0
[0F60:0E34][2014-08-11T15:02:04]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Why doesn't the install start? It is the same command that would normally be bound to a button and that would start the install.

I could execute the following line and that works, but I would prefer not to duplicate code.

```
model.PlanAction(Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.LaunchAction.Install);
```

Thank you,

Gary

Comment: Is your viewModel.InstallCommand initialized before you call it. I thnik that the problem is here: viewModel.InstallCommand.CanExecute(null)

Comment: It was my understanding that you should check to see if the command can be executed before you try to execute it. I have updated the log information with the latest. As you can see it is trying to execute the command.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would put a try/catch block in the DelegateCommand event handler and log any error message.

Comment: I added a try/catch block in the PlanAction event handler but I didn't receive an error.